# How to write all words of a string into different variables?

Tags: c++, string, cin

I want to get a line of strings and write every word into it's own variable, so that I can use them for example in if clauses.

I tried:

```
cin >> var1;  
cin >> var2;
cin >> var3;
cin >> var4;
```

But this only works if 4 words are entered. I need a way to count the words because I don't know if it's 1,2,3,4 or more words the user enters.

Maybe there is a way with getting the whole string:

```
getline(cin, string1);
```

And cut it into words after that.
Sorry, I searched a lot but I can't find a way.

I also tried to write the cinbuffer into a variable, but the only way I can do this is with

```
cin >> varx;
```

Which is only usefull if there is something in the cinbuffer. If not, the user gets asked for input again.

EDIT: Just found this, works for me. Thanks Anyway!
[C++ cin whitespace question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735315/c-cin-whitespace-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re on the right track. You can read a line with `getline()` then use an `istringstream` to treat that line as a stream of its own. Change this for whatever type `T` you happen to be using.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    using namespace std;

    vector<T> values;

    {
        string line;
        getline(cin, line);
        istringstream stream(line);

        // Read values into vector.
        copy(istream_iterator<T>(stream), istream_iterator<T>(),
            back_inserter(values));
    }

    cout << "Received " << values.size() << " values:\n";

    // Copy values to output.
    copy(values.begin(), values.end(),
        ostream_iterator<T>(cout, "\n"));

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @mohrphium: No problem. `<iterator>`, `<algorithm>`, and `<numeric>` are also really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Writing things to different variables like this is usually the wrong answer. It seems like you want something like an [array](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/).

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you use getline

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/

then use something like boost split to dump each item into an array

http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/strings/split/